# Why is Google Chrome not downloading anything?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, download

I click the direct link to the file and it just does nothing. No loading or anything. Some places work, some places don't. I also checked in my Downloads folder, nothing started downloading.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does it happen from any particular sites? Before clicking the link, hover the cursor over the link and look at the status-bar at the bottom. Is it an actual link to a file (eg `http://blah.com/file.zip`) or does it have some JavaScript (eg `javascript:blah();` or no status-bar at all)?

Comment: Yup, I've checked both. What I was trying to download was direct-linked. It happens on every website.

Comment: What happens if you right-click the link, select *Copy link as…* then paste that into the Omnibar and press `Enter`? Does it work then?

Comment: @Synetechinc. Nope.

Comment: Nope what? If you enter a URL directly to a file in the Omnibar, it still won’t download? What exactly happens? What are your download settings? (Wrench->Options->Under the hood->Downloads. Check the selected folder and *Ask where to save…*)

Comment: Nothing happens. Even rebooting doesn't fix it. I've even tried what you said with the downloads option

Comment: So the directory specified for the download location is definitely valid? Select the *Ask where to save* option; does it give you a `Save As` dialog? Does it happen with any specific kind of file? Try clicking the `Clear auto-opening settings` button below the Downloads section. Also, make sure that there is sufficient space on the drive(s) where the download directory, temp directory, and your User Profile are located. (Let me know if you need help checking what drives they are on.)

Comment: @Synetechinc. I had the `Save As` dialog option turned on, but when it stopped working I tried to get it to work by disabling it and downloading to my downloads folder (in `c:\users`) I searched the whole filesystem to see if the files where there. No files are downloaded at all.

Comment: Wow, strange. Test using a [new, clean User Profile](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142059). If it works, then your profile is damaged somehow and you’ll need to try to export as much of it as possible to a new one. If it still does not work, then it is a problem with the browser itself, so restore your original profile, then we’ll try to fix Chrome (go to Wrench->About Chrome and see if it is the latest version, and if not, let it update to see if that fixes it).

Comment: Thanks, it works! The New user profile got the job done. I'm currently working on getting all my personalized stuff over there (a lot).

Comment: I have a tip for that, but it is too big to fit here, and can’t contain any formatting, so see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, since the problem is definitely with your profile, what you want to do is to transfer as much of your existing profile to a new one as possible. The easiest way to do it, losing as little as possible is as follows:

1. Leave your old profile alone (ie, don’t move or delete anything from it, even consider zipping it, just in case)
2. Create a new profile if necessary (Chrome automatically creates one when run if one does not exist)
3. Close Chrome
4. Copy one of the files from your old profile to the new one, overwriting the existing one (or rename the existing one)
5. Run Chrome and test to see if the problem exists

   - If it does, delete that file and let Chrome re-create it (or delete the copied one and un-rename the other one)
   - Note the file that caused the problem
6. Go to 1. and repeat for another file until you have processed everything in your profile

Some notes:

- You can try copying a few things at a time, then narrow it down from there, especially since some things are unlikely to be the problem such as extensions, themes, scripts, local storage, etc. In fact, the **most likely** problem is **`Web Data`**. Try that one first.
- Once you have narrowed the problem down to (hopefully) a single file, then you can look into copying as much from the old one to the new one as possible (most of Chrome’s data files are in SQLite3 format, so you can/may/should be able to export the old data and import into the new one).
- Consider doing it the other way around: instead of migrating your old data to a new profile, just make a copy of your old profile and delete one file at a time from it (thus letting Chrome re-create it), then check to see if the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Try another browser and see if you have the same issue. Its probably an AV/firewall issue. A while back I had a conflict with Spyware Doctor and Chrome. Even if I created an exception to allow full access, it wouldn't work. Had to disable kernel compatibility mode. So check your protection settings for any anti-malware you are running including the not so obvious ones.

Comment: Other browsers work, no AV/firewall problems. I think it's an internal bug with Google Chrome. Guess I'll be using Firefox for a while now :|

Answer (score 1):

Head over to `about:flags` and check if you have the "New Download UI" enabled. If so, disable it.

Comment: Nope, it's currently disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time ago, just for some pages. For me it was my virus scanner (avast... or was it avira, one of them). I just exchanged it.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have those problems recently - from late 2020 onwards - do not do anything drastic, it's a "feature" not a bug and resetting profiles and other such things will just waste your time**.

This became a problem in the last few months, because Google - in their infinite wisdom (/s) - decided to block all insecure downloads on secure sites, without issuing any visible warnings. As a workaround you can right-click the link and choose "open in new tab", and even that sometimes fails when the page has some javascript-based redirection on link clicking, and Chrome breaks that redirection.

This disproportionately affects electronic and industrial component datasheet downloads. I do electrical engineering, and buy from DigiKey and other major online component distributors, who do billions of dollars in annual business. A key functionality on their website just got broken unilaterally by Google. Took me a hot minute to figure out - what a waste of time.

Worse yet: lots of sites have no control over how the *vendors* whose PDFs they just link to provide the data. I understand the security benefits of end-to-end encryption, but I also posit that if your internet connection is taken over by malware - whether local to your machine, or on a compromised router, or elsewhere - you're in deep trouble and preventing downloads from working over unencrypted HTML is not going to save you.

This is a pretty bad UX failure on Google's part, and it's not something that "just affects noobs". I can be considered a power user, I even do some web development, and it was baffling me for a good while. I don't routinely run third-party websites with developer console open, and that's the only place where warnings appear. I have no idea who thought it a clever idea - they have no job dealing with UX, because they don't understand the very fundamentals of it. This broke a lot of downloads - I'd say 80% of what I click on is now a no-op. If someone in the Chromium team proposed a feature that arbitrarily randomly made 80% of download links do nothing when clicked, they'd have been laughed out of the room. But if they use a security smoke screen, somehow this goes through... all this brilliant engineering "talent" and they can't get such basics right :(